# Interpolating point set into value contours?

Tags: python, php, interpolation

The task at hand is creating 'isobar' value contours that are interpolated from a point field of either the x/y or lat/lon type. I really have no idea where to begin mainly because this needs to be done in code...not pre-existing software.

Are there any algorithms or publications I should research further?

Data is more often that not irregularly spaced (not in a regular matrix/grid).

Algorithms need to function for both lat/lon and x/y data. Data is 2 dimensional so the z-axis is not a concern.

Comment: do these contours need to be overlain on a web-based interactive map?

Comment: Not necessarily. The only 'must' is that the resulting contour coordinates need to be accessible outside the code...i.e. the code dumps them to a text file so other apps can gain access. That however can easily be added to existing scripts.

Answer (score 3):

This article on the [marching squares algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) outlines the general algorithm. Here is a [good implementation](http://paulbourke.net/papers/conrec/), in various languages, though sadly not Python. Having said that, the algorithm basically just operates on arrays in loops, so ought to be reasonably easy to port.

I have used the [Java](http://paulbourke.net/papers/conrec/Conrec.java) version to do contours and can confirm that it works, in the sense that it coincided with those produced at the same scale from the same input data by the UK's Ordnance Survey. 
One caveat is that if you have areas where there are many of the same values in a contiguous block, and this value corresponds to one of your contour values, the algorithm can get stuck. I found it helpful to add a tiny random number to the input value to prevent this -- this does introduce minor inaccuracies, to be sure, but is not an issue in areas of sharp relief, pressure gradient, etc.

**EDIT**: Based on comments from the OP. There is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772710/contour-irregular-data-within-polygon) that uses scipy.interpolate to make an irregular grid and then plots it using matplotlib contouring routine. As these are both open source, you can just read the source code, available [here](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html)

Comment: This resource looks very promising...I've found there is a PHP implementation that will suffice just as well as Python. One question though, does the data need to be in a regular grid or can spacing vary?

Comment: Unfortunately, the comments in the code, and the structure of the loops themselves, mean, that as it is written, the data need to be regular.

Comment: It looks like this question on Stack Overflow not only answers your question, but does so in our favourite language, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772710/contour-irregular-data-within-polygon

Comment: Alright...I'll work with both of these resources and see what I come up with. I couldn't have asked for a better answer. Thanks!!

Comment: It doesn't seem that the interpolation source code is available at this site: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata. Is there another source?

Comment: http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html

Comment: As apposed to using matplotlib, are there any other functions to simply create and return the contour points themselves rather than try to draw them? I basically looking for the most efficient method to turn irregularly spaced lat/lon points into isoline contours.

Comment: What is wrong with the code that creates the contours? No one said you have to plot them, but they are created first.

Comment: Fair enough...I was just wondering if there was anything that *just* creates them. Let me get this straight; pyplot.contour takes in a regularly spaced grid in the form x and y and an array of corresponding values z (contour(x,y,z)). If data is not regular, griddata() can be used to interpolate it. Afterwards, how can one retrieve the contour points that are created?

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça - would the approach you outline work for me - https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28058/calculating-curvature-from-height-contours ?